# Add specific related field to response

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a controller with the action:

```
public function getCities(): JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json([City::all()], 200);
}
```

Entity City has relation to Country.

How I can add country.id for every item in the result City::all()?

Comment: how does city relate to country? if city belongs to country then you already have the country id on city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has amazing feature for creating virtual attributes. Add these lines to your City model for this:

`NOTIFICATION: I assume you have the CountryCity model`

```
public $appends = ['country_id'];

public function getCountryIdAttribute()
{
    $country = CountryCity::where('city_id',$this->id)
    if($country){
        return $country->id;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This will create one additional query for each City, this is what you want to avoid using eager loading.

Comment: I know this way is not optimal but in this way country_id is completely likes an attribute  and I thought this is what @GetUnstuk wants.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

The best way is to use eager loading, using :

```
City::with('country')->get();
```

Then, you can access country id like :

```
$city->country->id;
```

Comment: I want to have a country id in json response.